# Index not used when doing join on two text arrays using overlap operator with Postgresql 9.4

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Trying to optimize the join below, but cost still seems to be too high. Is there any way how to force postgres to use index when doing join on two text array fields?

```
             ->  Unique  (cost=16508500.04..16510899.32 rows=319904 width=38) (actual time=580978.121..581078.948 rows=415229 loops=1)
                   ->  Sort  (cost=16508500.04..16509299.80 rows=319904 width=38) (actual time=580978.120..581013.446 rows=415229 loops=1)
                         Sort Key: t992_1.name, t294_1.name
                         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 51186kB
                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16479249.17 rows=319904 width=38) (actual time=1.335..579142.184 rows=415229 loops=1)
                               Join Filter: (array_lowercase((t294_1.name)::character varying[]) && array_lowercase((t992_1.name)::character varying[]))
                               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 31577903
                               ->  Seq Scan on c04 t992_1  (cost=0.00..4106.69 rows=69848 width=195) (actual time=0.003..40.408 rows=69854 loops=1)
                                     Filter: __name_flag
                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 15
                               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..95.87 rows=458 width=83) (actual time=0.000..0.031 rows=458 loops=69854)
                                     ->  Seq Scan on cat t294_1  (cost=0.00..93.58 rows=458 width=83) (actual time=0.003..0.381 rows=458 loops=1)
```

The problematic part of the query is `array_lowercase(t294_1.name) && array_lowercase(t992_1.name)`. I have GIN index on both columns (with `array_lowercase`).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete query you are running

Comment: Added a bit more details. I can add the whole query, but the problem is mentioned there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've solved it by using slightly different function for the index. Original function as defined below is won't be used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_lowercase(character varying[])
  RETURNS character varying[] AS
$BODY$
    SELECT array_agg(q.tag) FROM (
        SELECT btrim(lower(unnest($1)))::varchar AS tag
    ) AS q;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
COST 100;`
```

But if the `array_lowercase` function is defined slightly differently using `text[]` instead of `character varying[]` it's picked and used automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_lowercase(text[])
  RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$
    SELECT array_agg(q.tag) FROM (
        SELECT btrim(lower(unnest($1))) AS tag
    ) AS q;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```